# Python Selenium Geckodriver Detected as Bot

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, recaptcha, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape the site skyscanner.com and they seem to very easily detect my code as a bot. I tried with fresh rotating proxies and 99% of the times they show a captcha at the very first search I make. I use this code for other sites and that doesn't happen, so I've no idea what else to change to avoid being detected so quickly. Another red flag I saw is that the same proxies if I try them on my personal computer, I don't see the captcha. So it must be some setup on selenium.

Here is the way I create a new driver:

```
def getDriver(proxy,proxy_port)
        proxy_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        # Proxy setup
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http",proxy)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(proxy_port))
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https",proxy)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port",int(proxy_port))
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl",proxy)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",int(proxy_port))
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp",proxy)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port",int(proxy_port))
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",proxy)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(proxy_port))
        # Remote DNS test
        proxy_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", True)
        # Disable CSS (breaks the done loading condition)
        #proxy_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
        # Disable images
        proxy_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
        # Disable flash
        proxy_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so','false')
        # User agent
        self.info(self.userAgent)
        proxy_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", self.userAgent)
        # Avoid detection variables
        proxy_profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
        proxy_profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=proxy_profile, firefox_options=options)
```

Any thoughts on something else to try and make it more difficult to detect? Thanks!

Comment: do you have some cookies on your personal computer with this sites, that you dont have in selenium?

Answer (score 1):

i've had the same situation like you've described. This is how i have solved it:

1. Make your request via selenium
2. Solve the captcha yourself
3. Save the cookies
4. Use these cookies on your future searches to avoid the captcha

here are the function to safe and load cookies:

```
def safe_cookies(driver):
    pickle_filename = "cookies.pkl"
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(pickle_filename, "wb"))

def load_cookies(driver):
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

    if len(cookies) > 0:
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)

        driver.refresh()
```

load the cookies back in every time you are loading the page for the first time:

```
...
driver.get("https://www.skyscanner.com/")
load_cookies(driver)
...
```

Comment: Interesting, but how can I do it manually moving the cookies from my personal computer to the selenium code? I run it headless on a server, I don’t have an interface for me to solve the captcha.

Comment: sry for the late reply. Never had a chance to extract cookies from my personal browser, but there are plenty solutions for this. After a quick search i've came across this repo: https://github.com/n8henrie/pycookiecheat (not tested by me).  Feel free to use one of those and see if you can get them extracted. Another way would be simply copy every cookie placed by the domain and copy name and value by hand in a txt file and read in via python